# Is a character in a variable is a letter or number

Tags: numbers, character, letter

I would like to find out how you can tell if a character in a variable is a letter or number

for example:
if I used the code: ABC123

How would I find out if a variable followed that pattern so if a inputted code would be DNM567 it would print "correct"
But if a code was DNM56T it would print "incorrect".

Many thanks

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Specify the programming language you are using, describe the problem unambiguously, and show your best effort so far in solving it. SO is not for writing code for your.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, or linearly scan the character array to ensure that no letter comes after a number.

More information about the question would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(myString, "^[A-Za-z]{3}[0-9]{3}$")) 
{
    // you got the right pattern...
}
```

edit: this is C# but regular expression can be found in almost any OOP language out there.